# Vue.JS: How to call function after page loaded?

Tags: vue.js

I have got next Vue component.
`Login` as calling Login function.
`checkAuth` -- is calling checking Authorization status between page refresh.

But how I can call `checkAuth` without pushing on button?

```js
var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
    props: ['username', 'password'],
    template: `
        <div id="auth">
            <form class="form-inline pull-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="UserName">User name</label>
                  <input type="username" v-model="username" class="form-control" id="UserName" placeholder="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click.prevent="sendLoginInfo()">LOGIN</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click.prevent="checkAuth()">CheckAuth</button>
            </form>
        </div>`,

    methods: { 
        //hash key-value
        sendLoginInfo: sendLoginInfo, // key (anyname) | value -> calling function name (from separate file) 
        
        //calling without brackets because we do need return from function, we need just function
        checkAuth: checkAuth // restore authorization after refresh page if user already have session!
    }
});
```

I tried to call it's from App:

```js
App = new Vue({ // App -- is need for overwrite global var. Global var need declarated abobe all function, because some it's function is calling from outside
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            topMenuView: "guestmenu",
            contentView: "guestcontent",
            username: "",
            password: "",

        },
        ready: function() {
            checkAuth(); // Here

        }
    }
)
```

But it's look like it's calling when not all components are loaded,

```js
function checkAuth() {
    // we should NOT send any data like: loginData because after refreshing page
    // all filds are empty and we need to ask server if he have authorize session

    console.log("Checking if user already have active session");

    this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/checkAuthorization').then(function(response) {
            console.log("server response: ", response.data)
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Here I am getting error:

`authorization.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`

I tried to do:

```js
{
// ...
    methods: { //hash key-value
      sendLoginInfo : sendLoginInfo, // key (anyname) | value -> calling function name (from separate file) 
      //calling without brackets because we do need return from function, we need just function

    },
    ready()
    {
      checkAuth()
    }
// ...
}
```

But again got error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 29):

Let see `mounted()` I think it is help

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: This helps but I'm unsure where to add the Mounted function within my code - I'm using SFC format with app.vue etc.

Answer (score 22):

```
// vue js provides us `mounted()`. this means `onload` in javascript.

mounted () {
  // we can implement any method here like
   sampleFun () {
      // this is the sample method you can implement whatever you want
   }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If you need run code after 100% loaded with **image** and **files**, test this in `mounted()`:

```
mounted() {

  document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      console.log('Page completed with image and files!')
      // fetch to next page or some code
    }
  }

}
```

More info: [Event onreadystatechange - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event)

Comment: Thank you for this tip! This was exactly what I was looking for along with mounted().

Answer (score 9):

You can use the **`mounted()`** **Vue Lifecycle Hook**. This will allow you to call a method before the page loads.

This is an implementation example:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>Welcome our site {{ name }}</h1>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```js
var app = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      name: ''
  },
  mounted: function() {
      this.askName() // Calls the method before page loads
  },
  methods: {
      // Declares the method
      askName: function(){
          this.name = prompt(`What's your name?`)
      }
  }
})
```

This will get the **`prompt method`**'s value, insert it in the variable **`name`** and output in the **`DOM`** after the page loads. You can check the code sample **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/mercenariomode/d3mfsqcL/3/)**.

You can read more about **Lifecycle Hooks** [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks).

Answer (score 7):

You import the function from outside  the main instance, and don't add it to the methods block. so the context of `this` is *not* the vm.

Either do this:

```
ready() {
  checkAuth.call(this)
}
```

or add the method to your methods first (which will make Vue bind `this` correctly for you) and call this method:

```
methods: {
  checkAuth: checkAuth
},
ready() {
  this.checkAuth()
}
```

Comment: How can the same be done in vue.js 2. I have tried the second option using `mounted` but it does not work.

Comment: Well, it should work with `mounted()`, so your problem is likely to be something else. What that is I can'T say without any code. You should open another topic maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Vue `watch()` **life-cycle hook**, can be used

*html*

```
<div id="demo">{{ fullName }}</div>
```

*js*

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Bar',
    fullName: 'Foo Bar'
  },
  watch: {
    firstName: function (val) {
      this.fullName = val + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    lastName: function (val) {
      this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + val
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function on load like this:

```
methods:{
     checkAuth: function() {your logic here}
 },
 mounted(){
    this.checkAuth()
 },
```